# Bootstrap Navbar displaying incorrectly on only one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have been learning about Responsive design lately, and am attempting to retrofit a site I have been working on with Bootstrap in order to make it Responsive.  I am having a strange issue, however, in that on all of my pages except for my Index page, the navbar works (almost) exactly as desired - it renders properly, and it shows the mobile version when I shrink the width of the page.

However, on my Index page, I end up with some amalgamation of a navbar that seems to be the mobile dropdown-list navbar applied to the entire page even at a full 1080p screen size.  This is the case at all times, without me having opened the navbar dropdown (which shouldn't show at 1080p...).

So, the logical conclusion is that there's some error in my index page, if the layout itself works on every other page.  But I can't see what would be causing the issue:

Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
@*<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">*@
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Hire Right</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts") @* -- All jquery/bootstrap is loaded properly in this single bundle -- *@
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationLinks" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HireRight</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationLinks">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">@Html.ActionLink("New Clients", "NewClients", "Client")</li>
                    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">@Html.ActionLink("Returning Clients", "Order", "Order")</li>
                    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">@Html.ActionLink("Get in Touch", "Contact", "Contact")</li>
                    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">@Html.ActionLink("Order", "Order", "Order")</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="body-content" style="padding-left: 15px; margin-top: 25px;">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer style="height: 20px; clear: both;">
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Hire Right Consultants</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/indexDivScripts.js"></script>
<style>
.titleRow {
    border: 2px dotted red;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row titleRow" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; clear: both;">
    <ol class="list-item-no-bullet">
        <li class="btn btn-default" style="width: 25%;" onclick="displayInfoDiv('WhyUseHireRight');">Why Use Hire Right?</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" style="width: 25%;" onclick="displayInfoDiv('Consultants');">Consultants</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" style="width: 25%;" onclick="displayInfoDiv('WhoWeServe');">Occupational Categories</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: #993333; padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;" class="row">
<!-- This was originally a Jumbotron, but it seemed to be causing its own
set of issues so I styled it as a simple div with a hardcoded background color -->
    <div style="width: 35%; float: left;">
        <h1>Hire Right Testing</h1>
        <h3 style="padding-left: 60px;"><i>Hire Right, the First Time</i></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row titleRow" style="float: left; width: 40%;">
        <h4>content</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="infoDiv" hidden="hidden">
</div>
<div id="introDiv" class="row titleRow" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-3" style="border: 2px dotted red;">
        <p>
            content
        </p>
        <p>
            content
        </p>
        <img src="~/Content/indexPicture.jpg" alt="indexImage" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6" style="border: 2px dotted red;">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="border: 2px dotted red;">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="WhoWeServe" hidden="hidden">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("WhoWeServePartial"); }
</div>
<div id="Consultants" hidden="hidden">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("ConsultantsInformationPartial");}
</div>
<div id="WhyUseHireRight" hidden="hidden">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("WhyUseHireRightPartial");}
</div>
</div>
```

I have some SASS files I was working with as well, though I can't imagine they'd be related?  In addition to using them for the general design of the site, I did try to recolor the navbar, which worked, though recoloring of the links isn't working for some reason with code like this:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: $darkRed;
    a { color: $black; }
    a:hover { color: $ltgray; }
}
```

Here is an image depicting the problem.  Both images were from a screen that had simply been loaded without anything being clicked on, and a full 1080p browser window:
http://tinypic.com/r/2h2i3pv/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was messing everything up, one of my partial views had a style segment that set the width of list items to 100%.